# how to send image with file

Tags: android, image, web-services, file

I have a write a code for the registration for a application. Now at the time of registration, user has to select his image that will not go with the parameters but as a file with parameter.
Now I am setting a image from my phone to check whether the webservice(URL) is getting hit or not. I am just putting the name of the image in the code and trying to get its path. 
here is my code::-

```
String url ="http://somesite.com/ws/register.php?username="+ regName + "&password=" + regPass + "&email=" + regEmail + "&age=" + regAge + "&sex=qee&Device_Id=12332weewr";
         try {
             ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();



            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("file", "<thumbnail>"));


            File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile()+File.separator +"krish.jpeg");
            Bitmap thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("file");
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 

            thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap
            byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
            String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("file", encodedImage));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fileName", "dev.jpeg"));
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mimeType","image/jpeg"));

        String res= CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(url, postParameters);
```

but in **thumbnail** I am not getting image accurate path. it is returning **null**

Comment: you need pass image to bits encodeToString

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("file");
```

i think problems is here, maybe you are wanted to write something like this?

```
Bitmap thumbnail = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: it's strange, make sure that file exists (or path of file you are getting here Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile()+File.separator +"krish.jpeg" is true)

Comment: krish.jpg is a name of a pic that is saved in my phone's directory. I m just putting its name here so that i can check whether it is hitting the webservice or not?? once it hits the webservice, i will remove the name of image and and leave that option for user to insert his personal image.

Comment: "krish.jpg is a name of a pic that is saved in my phone's directory." but are you sure, that this pic exists at exactly this path Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile()+File.separator +"krish.jpeg" ? You can just pass to BitmapFactory.decodeFile wrong file path and, and method will return null. So thumbnail will be null. After change BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath()); code must work, i am tried (but only with correct file path passed to decodeFile method).

Comment: I am getting the path in "file" it is returning me this result 

file = File(id = 830058832776)
path = "/storage/sdcard/krish.jpeg"(id = 830058833072)

yes this image is there because I saved this specially for the testing few hours back.